# fusionauth docker installation on windows failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fusionauth

I am trying to install fusionauth in my windows with this docker command provided in fusionauth's official site.

```
curl -o docker-compose.yml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-containers/master/docker/fusionauth/docker-compose.yml && curl -o .env https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-containers/master/docker/fusionauth/.env && docker-compose up
```

I keep getting this error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like FusionAuth can't connect to your PostgreSQL database. Are you certain that the PostgreSQL part of the Docker Compose is coming up correctly? That would be the first thing I would look into.

Comment: well. that was the dockerfile they provided in their official site.

Comment: Can you uncomment the lines: 
`#   ports:
#     - 5432:5432`

in the docker-compose file and see if you can connect to postgres directly?

Comment: You could also post the earlier startup logs for PostgreSQL to see if it came up ok.